# How to map specific column cells to other specific column cells in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to see if I can replace contents of a set of cells in a column with a set of cells in a column from other location in the same table.

Example:

```
Book
-------
id payload
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
5  e
```

I want a query that will make it the following

```
Book
-------
id payload
1  c
2  e
3  c
4  d
5  e
```

Say I want payload of 3,5 to replace contents of 1,2.

Here is my attempt:

```
update 
(

select id, payload 
    from Books
    where id in (1,2)
    
) as normal_book_1

join

(

select id, payload 
    from Books
    where id in (3,5)

) as normal_book_2

set normal_book_1.payload = normal_book_2.payload;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self join with the mapping of the columns in the `ON` clause:

```
UPDATE Book b1
INNER JOIN Book b2 ON (b1.id, b2.id) IN ((1, 3), (2, 5))
SET b1.payload = b2.payload;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d77e22c469e7f07a4956310d0212840f).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute two `UPDATE` statements, as in:

```
update books
set payload = (select payload from books where id = 3)
where id = 1

update books
set payload = (select payload from books where id = 5)
where id = 2;
```